# Parse/Swift - "AnyObject is not convertible to String

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to populate a table view with items from an array of `PFObjects`:

```
var obj: PFObject = self.usersArray[indexPath.row] 
cell.textLabel?.text = obj.objectForKey("username")
```

But if I do it that way I get the compiler error: "AnyObject is not convertible to String"
That's the way I always did it with Objective-C, how do I sort this out?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you can use the shorter syntax of `obj["username"]` instead of `obj.objectForKey("username")` :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast explicitly to avoid this error:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = obj.objectForKey("username") as String
```

This is because `obj.objectForKey(...)` returns an object of type `AnyObject`, and Swift does not permit implicitly casting this to another type, while Objective-C does (imagine it being compulsory to write **`(NSString *)`**`obj.objectForKey(...)` in Objective-C).

Answer (score 0):

Why not write your code in a simpler way and stop using `objectForKey`. In the latest `Parse` library the `PFObject` supports direct access to a custom object's properties by using the `[]` notation ([documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-classes/iOS)).

Also why is textLabel an optional? You should unwrap that before using it. So replace `?` with `!` or remove it completely if `textLabel` is not declared as an optional.

Basically your code could look like this:

```
var obj: PFObject = self.usersArray[indexPath.row] 
cell.textLabel!.text = obj["username"] as NSString // Remove ! if textLabel is not an optional
```

Let me know if this works for you.